# How are SSIS Precedence Constraints Evaluated?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

[image]Maybe this question seems very basic and elementary but I need some clarification.

In SSIS the following Constraints are available to control component execution flow:

- Logical AND. All constraints must evaluate to true.
- Logical OR. At least one constraint must evaluate to true.

I have a very simple package I am using to test the conditions described.

A Process Task - calls a batch file that returns a string value and exit code.

The Process Task receives the value from the batch file as a StandardOutputVariable and assigns it to my user defined variable User::BatchExecutionCode

A Script Task - for validation, displays the acquired value from my user variable so I can visually see and affirm that the expected value is getting passed

An Execute SQL Task - That simply does a SELECT GETDATE().

I have setup a Logical AND condition between the Script Task and Process Task that mandates:

1. Constraint - Task execution must "Complete"
2. Expression - @BatchExecutionCode == "0"

When I execute, both tasks prior to the final "Execute SQL" task complete and I get a visual message box showing the value of my variable as "0" but the execution just stops afterward and never executes the last task after evaluation.

What is the problem? According to the stated conditions for execution, the conditions have been met. So exactly how are the precedence constraints being evaluated.

EDIT: For clarification, In the screenshot the value of @BatchExecutionCode has been passed to User::Result variable via the Script Task. Thats why the Expression says @Result == "0". Either way, the results is still the same

Comment: Could you share a print screen of your package ?

Comment: Is there any chance the Script Task is not correctly assigning the value to @Result? Does the script task do anything besides the assignment?

Comment: @billinkc, The value of Result is just a direct transfer of the Value contained in BatchExecutionCode which is a string data type. Nothing additional is being performed. But to your point, if I were to remove the Script Task component and change the expression to BatchExecutionCode == "0" the results would be the same as I've already tried that also.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason should be @Result doesn't equal "0", you can confirm that with a post execute breakpoint on you script task.

You can use the following article to confirm what's really in this variable.

http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-using-breakpoints-231/